# Matlab, extract some cell elements to another one

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I have a cell of some string and I want to select some string from it and save them to another cell.For example if I have this cell. I mean some efficient method without using loop.

Thanks

```
labels= 'aaaa'
        'bbbb'
        'ccc'
        'dddd'
```

and

```
idx=
    1
    2
```

The result be:

```
   g=
    'aaaa'
    'bbbb'
```

I use this code but this is wrong.

```
G_no=max(idx);% idx is an array of some number
g={};
for i=1:G_no
   G_mem=find(idx==i);
   g{i,:}=labels{1,G_mem};% labels is  a cell of some string
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after...

```
labels =  {'aaaa','bbbb','cccc','dddd'};
idx = [1,2];
newlabels = labels(idx);
disp(newlabels)
disp(iscell(newlabels))
```

output:

```
'aaaa'    'bbbb'

1
```

Therefore, `newlables` is a cell object

Comment: u r right. I think i don't explain the question well. I want to save to another cell. for example the above result is saved in first row of cell the second result in the second row of cell but without loop.

Comment: If the above is not what you're after then I'm not sure I understand your question?